# How to choose a table that has the table name : "group"?

Tags: mysql

I have a table. Name of the table is "group"

I run query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM GROUP
```

There exist error like this:

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group 
 LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1
```

Any solution to solve my problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use backquote :

```
SELECT * FROM `GROUP`
```

you can also alias your table name for later use in `WHERE` clause for instance:

```
SELECT * FROM `GROUP` g WHERE g.id = 1
```

Comment: Or stop using [**RESERVED WORDS**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) as table names

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza, Why? I using reserved words and it's no problem

Comment: I think avoid using a reserved word is a good practice, but not impossible.